# How to get data from JSON in a service angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a JSON file that looks like this

```
{
 "user": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "data": [
        {
          "userName": "iheb",
          "useremail": "",
          "userPassword": "kkk"
        }
      ],
      "questionnaireListe": [
        {
          "questionnaire": [
            {
              "id": 2,
              "section": [
                {
                  "sectionName": "produit 1",
                  "question": [
                    {
                      "questionName": "question 1",
                      "answer": [
                        {
                          "answerName": "reponse 1"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "sectionName": "produit 2",
                  "question": [
                    {
                      "questionName": "question 2",
                      "answer": [
                        {
                          "answerName": "reponse 1"
                        },
                        {
                          "answerName": "reponse 2"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

and a srvice which has a fuction to get a data from it that looks like this

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class QuestionnaireService {

  constructor(private _Http:HttpClient) { } 
  getUser() {
    return this._Http.get("http://localhost:3000/user");
  }
}
```

and a component.ts that looks like this

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { QuestionnaireService } from '../questionnaire.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Answer } from '../answer';
import { UserQuestion } from '../userQuestion';
import { UserSection } from '../userSection';
import { UserQuestionnaire } from '../userQuestionnaire';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  user:object;

  ques:Object;
  identifiant:number;
  constructor(public router:Router ,private questionnaire:QuestionnaireService,private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.identifiant = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.afficherUser();
  }
checkChange(event:Event,a:number,b:string,c:string){
  let s=<HTMLInputElement> event.target;
  let aa=true;
  let bb=true;
  let cc=true;
  let f= new Answer(<string>s.value);
  let d= new UserQuestion(c,[f]);
  let e= new UserSection(b,[d]);
  let g= new UserQuestionnaire(a,[e]);
  if (s.checked == true){
    for (let x of this.user['questionnaireListe']){
      for(let y of x.questionnaire){
        if (y.id == a){
          cc=false;
          for(let z of y.section){
            if(z.sectionName == b){
              bb=false;
              for (let u of z.question){
                if(u.questionName == c){
                  aa=false;
                  u.answer.push(f);
                  break;
                }
              }
              if(aa == true) {
                z.question.push(d);           
                aa=false;       
                break;
              }
            }
          }
          if(bb == true){
            y.section.push(e);
            bb=false;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if(cc == true) {
        x.questionnaire.push(g); 
        cc =false;
        break;
      }
      }
    }
    else{
      for (let x of this.user['questionnaireListe']){
        for(let y of x.questionnaire){
          if (y.id == a ){
            for(let z of y.section){
              if(z.sectionName == b ){
                for (let u of z.question){
                  if(u.questionName == c && u['answer'].length >= 2){
                    let y= u.answer.indexOf(f);
                    u.answer.splice(y,1);
                  }
                  else if(u.questionName == c && u['answer'].length == 1){
                    let xx= z.question.indexOf(d);
                    z.question.splice(xx,1);

                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

and i have a service that looks like this

```js
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { QuestionnaireService } from './questionnaire.service';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthUserService implements OnInit{
user:Object;
aa=true;
  constructor(private router:Router, private questionnaire:QuestionnaireService) { }
  logIn = false;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.afficherUser();

  }
  afficherUser(){
    this.questionnaire.getUser().subscribe(Response=>{ 
     this.user=Response;
    })
  }


  login(t){


  for (let x of this.user['data']){
    if (t.userName == x.userName && t.userPassword == x.userPassword){
        this.aa=false;
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/userQuestionnaireListe');
      } 
    }
      if (this.aa == true){
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login-user');      
      }
  }
}
```

so the method I used in the component

```js
for (let x of this.user['questionnaireListe']){
      for(let y of x.questionnaire){
        if (y.id == a)
...
```

works fine but when I use it in the service

```js
  for (let x of this.user['data']){
    if (t.userName == x.userName && t.userPassword == x.userPassword){
...
```

doesn't wanna work and it gives me the error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

I don't  know where's the problem why the same function works in the component.ts but not in the service??
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: `this.user=Response;` but Response is `{ "user": {...}}`

Comment: so how do you think it should be written ?? @AndrewAllen

Comment: just log this.user in service and check it has property named data

Answer (score -1):

this is because when you call it inside the service you are trying to access the user object before it's initialized. on way to fix this would be to create a class representing the user object with default values for data and other values. then make the user object of that class.

```
class UserModel {
 id: number;
 data = [];
 questionnaireListe = [];

}
```

then make **user** inside **AuthUserService** type of **UserModel**

```
user: UserModel = new UserModel();
```

Comment: Personally I would make it an interface instead, especially when working with JSON, but that's more a personal preference. I find interfaces easier to work with when it comes to pure datamodels. Classes are nice if you need to utilize a constructor or use methods. But I do think you're right otherwise.

Comment: you are right it works with interface too but in case you want default values class are the way. so @3bouda you can choose

Comment: I did what you've said but another Error has appeared: in the afficherUse() methode in ` subscribe(Response=>{ this.user=Response;` this.user gives me the error **The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead? Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'UserQuestionnaireListe': id, data, questionnaireListe** @MikeAraya @IngeOlaisen

Comment: @MikeAraya @IngeOlaisen so I went to the other service and add `return this._Http.get<Fuser>("http://localhost:3000/user");` and the error in the component.ts has disappeared but in the browser it gives me an error **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined** what should I do ??

Comment: try naming Respoice to another name. I think you are using something from another package without knowing or give it type like so: 
  ``` afficherUser(){
    this.questionnaire.getUser().subscribe((Response :UserModel)=>{ 
     this.user=Response;
    })
  }```

Answer (score -1):

did you make the command for watching the json in the 
**npm install -g json-server**
**json-server --watch src/data/name.json --port 3000**

You may have forgotton to write the model of the object